# Eager vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way to force render a component even if it is hidden by v-if or other logic blocking methods?

I have a component A, which comunicates with component B by simple global $emit system.

Component B begins to listen to global events on "created" hook, and when I press a button on component A a counter in component B increments by one.

Everything works fine when both components are rendered, since both component's created hook has fired.

It doesn't work however if component B is hidden from the start either by v-if, or in my case - a hidden v-dialog component with v-model = false.

It only requires showing the component B once to trigger created() hook, and everything works fine and I can even hide it back. It's not a perfect solution so I was wandering if there is an "eager" option or something like that, that trigers component logic even if it's hidden

Comment: Don't think this mechanism exists. Anyway, since it's a global event, why not handle it in global state (e.g. Pinia) ?

Comment: If the component isn't rendered then it's not possible.  The [lifecycle of a component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram), which starts and ends when a component is rendered and destroyed respectively, shows no way for any code to run outside this lifecycle.  When destroyed, the component state is lost. There are different strategies for resolving your problem, such as using global state or maybe using [v-show](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-show) instead of v-if. With v-show the component is still rendered while hidden.